# Stern-Gerlach experiment and probability theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, probability

I'm trying to understand why, precisely, we cannot use classical probability theory in quantum mechanics. I came across an explanation of the Stern-Gerlach experiment, saying that if $X$ and $Z$ are Bernoulli random variables for the $x$ and $z$-spin of an electron, if we measure the $z$ spin first, the expectation of the $x$ spin is always $0$. If we measure the $x$ spin first, the expectation of the $z$ spin is always $0$. The idea is that this then contradicts $\mathbb{E}(XZ)=\mathbb{E}(ZX)$ from classical probability theory. I have two questions.

Why does the random variable $XZ$ represent a measurement of $X$ first, and then $Z$? I would think the conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}(X|z)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z|x)$ are the relevant things to look at. But then what does this have to do with non-commutativity of $X$ and $Z$?

I think I'm also not exactly understanding the claims of the experiment as well. My understanding is, you need three Stern-Gerlach detectors to see something interesting. You send an electron through a $Z$ field and filter out the down spins, then you send the result through an $X$ field, and filter out the down $x$-spins, and you send the result through another $Z$ field and you get a 50-50 distribution of $z$-spins. I'm not exacting seeing how this is the same as the explanation in the first paragraph. If the spins are +1/2 and -1/2, the expectation of $X$ and $Z$ should be $0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini, gave the relevant link above. In simple terms, probabilities of two independent events add up. That's how probabilities work. In quantum physics it is the probability amplitudes that add up, and since the amplitudes a complex-valued, the magnitude of their sum can be smaller than the individual component's magnitude. This is not possible with strictly non-negative probabilities

Comment: @Cryo My question is really why is this necessary though? I understand there is a non-commutative probability theory that is working here, but why is it necessary? What experiment made physicists realize that position and momentum cannot be modeled as random variables in the classical sense?

Comment: @Cryo The information on Bell's theorem that I've found, seems to suggest that if you have a probability space with 3 Bernoulli random variables defined on that space, then their inner-products satisfy $<X_1,X_2>+<X_2,X_3>\leq 1-<X_1,X_3>$. But, apparently this does not happen in the Stern-Gerlach experiment, which would be a reason to say we can't use classical probability. I still am reviewing that argument though, and I haven't made sense of it yet.

Comment: @user124910, is this about history of science, or about science? Stern-Gerlach could have been  the first one, but now quantum mechanics is a working horse in Physics and Chemistry, so not sure it matters which experiment was first. It may matter what is the minimal thing you need to get going. IMHO, that's [Born Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule). This rule connects wavefunctions to probabilities and leads to situation where wavefunctions are combinable (since Schrodinger equation is linear), but probabilities are not

Comment: Note that this rule is a postulate, on which everything is built. It was discovered as a result of multiple historical accidents and was retained as a minimal essence of what is needed for QM

Comment: @Cryo I'm not sure if it's a history of science problem. The Born rule works for computing probabilities, but I'd like to know why it is necessary. Why does the classical interpretation need this extension to work here? For example, you can imagine that position is a classical random variable and $|\psi(x)|^2$ is its density. Then $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x|\psi(x)|^2dx$. If $\hat{X}$ is the position operator, you can also write this as $<\psi,\hat{X}\psi>$. Why do we need to adopt this approach though?

Comment: Does the Stern-Gerlach, or another experiment, force you to conclude the $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x|\psi(x)|^2dx$ approach is insufficient? Perhaps because the probabilities do not add subadditively as you would expect? Bell's inequality seems to imply hidden variables do not exist and quantum mechanics is non-local, but I'm not sure what this means in terms of classical probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what sources you used so far, but there is a limit to how much you can expect from the forum. There are good books on quantum mechanics out there. For your types of questions, I would probably suggest something like [Ballentine](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=psYuzgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)

The difference between how, I think, you are thinking about $\mathbb{E}\left[J_X\right]$ and how one would think about it in QM, is that the latter is very much about changing the state of the system, you subject system to measurement, it's state collapses into one of the possible states, this gives you the measurement, following this the system evolves from the state it collapsed into. Hence if you measure $J_X$ and then $J_Z$ one can talk about order of these, and it is not the same thing as conditioning joint distribution to extract $\mathbb{E}\left[J_X|j_z\right]$. I think it is more like $do$-calculus operations in a causal model.

It so happens that linear operators, with their commutation relations, can encode the inherent order one imposes on the system when one measures one property and then another, collapsing the system state after each measurement.